# Duda sobre lenguaje ensamblador ensamblador yasm x86 con ubuntu

Tags: ensamblador, x86

Necesito implementar un vector o arreglo de n elemento de 32 bits para comenzar a desarrollar un código, como puedo hacer esta primera parte.

Gracias.

Es que lo que pasa se como escribir un arreglo de 8 elementos con 32 bits; esto seria asi `arr dd 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8` pero como puedo hacer un arreglo de n elementos seria algo asi `arr dd n`

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que has intentado? preguntas que dicen tengo este deber resuélvanlo no son bien recibidas.

Comment: Es que lo que pasa se como escribir un arreglo de 8 elementos con 32 bits; esto seria asi `arr dd 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8` pero como puedo hacer un arreglo de n elementos seria algo asi `arr dd n`

Comment: `arr TIMES 32 DD 0` te da un array de 32 DD's inicializados en 0

Comment: @alo Malbarez Si pero lo que pasa que la instruccion `TIMES` es para nasm y yo estoy utilizando yasm